# How to make network call from Background service?

Tags: android, networking, service, call

this is my service Interface

```
public interface ContactService {

void postPhoneContacts(@NonNull ContactServiceListener serviceListener, int id, List<UserProfileInfo> userInfo);
}
```

This is mybackground service from where i want to make a network call
 How to intsantiate Contact Service Interface here? I am getting Null Pointer Exception. 
 From Fragment I am starting this service. Please help me this out

```
public class UploadContactBgService extends Service {

private ContactService contactService;
private int userId;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    List<UserProfileInfo> contactList = getContactsFromPhone();
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new PostContactEvent(contactList));
  /*  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    userId = prefs.getInt(LoginPresenter.PREF_USER_ID, 0);
    if (userId != 0) {
        postPhoneBookContactList(userId, contactList);

    }*/
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private List<UserProfileInfo> getContactsFromPhone() {

    //Read Column names of ContactsContract table to get contact info from phone book
    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    Uri DATA_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
    String ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String PHONE_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    String EMAIL_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    String DATA_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID;
    String ADDRESS_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    String ORG_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    String DATA_MIME_TYPE = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
    String EVENT_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    String EVENT_START_DATE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE;
    String NOTE_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    String WEB_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    String RELATION_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Relation.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;

    int CONTACT_TYPE_MOBILE = 1;
    int CONTACT_TYPE_WORK = 2;
    int CONTACT_TYPE_HOME = 3;
    int CONTACT_TYPE_WORK_FAX = 4;
    int CONTACT_TYPE_HOME_FAX = 5;
    int CONTACT_TYPE_PAGER = 6;
    int CONTACT_TYPE_OTHER = 7;
    int USER_PROFILE_TYPE = 2;

    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");
    List<UserProfileInfo> userInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        do {
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID));

            UserProfileInfo userInfo = new UserProfileInfo();
            UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();
            UserType userType = new UserType();
            /**
             * Querying the table ContactsContract.Data to retrieve individual items like
             home phone, mobile phone, work email etc corresponding to each contact
             */
            Cursor dataCursor = cr.query(DATA_CONTENT_URI, null,
                    DATA_CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId,
                    null, null);


            if (dataCursor.moveToFirst()) {

                /**
                 * checking if respective contactId has contact number or not
                 * If yes..then only add that user to list
                 * otherwise read next user
                 */

                int hasContactNumber = Integer.parseInt(dataCursor.getString(
                        dataCursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

                if (hasContactNumber == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Getting Display Name
                String displayName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                profile.setName(displayName);
                do {

                    // Getting Phone numbers
                    List<Contact> phones = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_MIME_TYPE)).equals(PHONE_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                        Contact contactNum = new Contact();
                        ContactTypeDm contactTypeDm = new ContactTypeDm();
                        switch (dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))) {
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                String homePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                userInfo.setUserName(homePhone);
                                contactNum.setContactNumber(homePhone);
                                contactTypeDm.setContactTypeId(CONTACT_TYPE_HOME);
                                contactNum.setContactTypeDm(contactTypeDm);
                                phones.add(contactNum);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                String mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                userInfo.setUserName(mobilePhone);
                                contactNum.setContactNumber(mobilePhone);
                                contactTypeDm.setContactTypeId(CONTACT_TYPE_MOBILE);
                                contactNum.setContactTypeDm(contactTypeDm);
                                phones.add(contactNum);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                String workPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                userInfo.setUserName(workPhone);
                                contactNum.setContactNumber(workPhone);
                                contactTypeDm.setContactTypeId(CONTACT_TYPE_WORK);
                                contactNum.setContactTypeDm(contactTypeDm);
                                phones.add(contactNum);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                                String other = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                userInfo.setUserName(other);
                                contactNum.setContactNumber(other);
                                contactTypeDm.setContactTypeId(CONTACT_TYPE_OTHER);
                                contactNum.setContactTypeDm(contactTypeDm);
                                phones.add(contactNum);
                                break;
                        }
                        userInfo.setContacts(phones);
                    }


                    // Getting EMails
                    if (dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_MIME_TYPE)).equals(EMAIL_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                        switch (dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))) {
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME:
                                String homeEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                profile.setEmail(homeEmail);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK:
                                String workEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                profile.setEmail(workEmail);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    // Getting Organization details
                    if (dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_MIME_TYPE)).equals(ORG_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                        String companyName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        String title = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data4"));
                        profile.setOrgName(companyName);
                        profile.setTitle(title);
                    }

                    // Getting BDay
                    if (dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_MIME_TYPE)).equals(EVENT_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                        int indexEvent = dataCursor.getColumnIndex(EVENT_START_DATE);
                        String dobStr = dataCursor.getString(indexEvent);
                        profile.setBDay(dobStr);
                    }

                    //Getting Note
                    if (dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_MIME_TYPE)).equals(NOTE_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                        String note = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        profile.setNotes(note);
                    }


                    //Getting Postal Address Details...
                    if (dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_MIME_TYPE)).equals(ADDRESS_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                        String street = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data4"));
                        String city = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data7"));
                        String state = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data8"));
                        String postalCode = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data9"));

                        Address addressInfo = new Address();
                        addressInfo.setStreet(street);
                        addressInfo.setCity(city);
                        addressInfo.setZip(postalCode);
                        addressInfo.setState(state);
                        userInfo.setAddress(addressInfo);
                    }

                    //Getting Website
                    if (dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_MIME_TYPE)).equals(WEB_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                        String webUrl = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        profile.setWebsite(webUrl);
                    }

                    //Getting Relation
                    if (dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_MIME_TYPE)).equals(RELATION_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                        String relationship = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        profile.setRelationShip(relationship);
                    }

                }
                while (dataCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            userType.setUserTypeId(USER_PROFILE_TYPE);
            profile.setUserType(userType);
            userInfo.setUserProfile(profile);
            userInfoList.add(userInfo);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return userInfoList;
}

public void postPhoneBookContactList(int id, List<UserProfileInfo> userInfoList) {

    contactService.postPhoneContacts(new ContactServiceListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UserProfileInfo responseBody) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new GetSyncedContactListEvent(responseBody));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
        }
    }, id, userInfoList);
}
}
```

Comment: Reading contacts from service ater reading I want to send contact list to our server using background service. But how to instantiate Contact service here?

Comment: the commented code in onStart() where I am trying to amke a network call