# How to make network calls on Android with an app in the background

Tags: android, performance, react-native

I am building a react-native app that launches a series of network requests (both UDP, HTTP) when it receives a special kind of notification, or based on a delayed execution.

However it turns out that after the first or second call, it enqueues the calls, without making them. If I open the applications, the remaining network calls are made, and the process continues.

It's a normal issue given that there is a specific doc page inside Android documentation targeting this behaviour:

- [Excessive Wi-Fi Scanning in the Background](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/bg-wifi)
- [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/bg-network-usage)

I have read and research over SO: [Best place to make network calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216992/best-place-to-make-network-calls), [How to make network call from Background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048434/how-to-make-network-call-from-background-service) but those methods did not work to bypass the obstacle. I can require the user to deactivate "battery optimisation" if required, but that did not work either.

I should mention that I am using React Native in order to handle the lifecycle and trigger the network calls, so they are running inside an Activity that is not in the background or when the phone is locked. I believe there should be ways moving things to a) a background thread or b) an Android service.

I really appreciate any response, experience or links that would help me address this problem.

Comment: there is no such thing as a "background activity"

Comment: I think it is easily understandable that I am talking about an activity-based app running on the background or with the phone locked. You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background. I'll edit it anyway to clarify further reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would want to trigger these calls in a HeadlessJS setup. To ensure to subsequent calls are made, either try reducing all the responses to a single API call, or use Promise.all to resolve it. Multiple calls might fail due to how battery optimisations are designed.

To work around such battery optimisations, you will have to promote the HeadlessJs task into a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)) (Android 7+), which you can do with native code, or calling it from NativeModules from the JS side.

Comment: I believe the restrictions to subsequent calls are more on the Executor implementation of react-native-<tcp | udp> rather than the JS calls to it. So far I tried those solutions without much success. I also tried to acquire the wifi and power locks